# Google Form Upload files to specific new folder based on the value submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have form with 2 fields, lets say the name of the form is **CV Drops**

1. Name
2. Uploaded files button

So, by default when people are uploading their files it will be keep in my Google Drive under folder **CV Drops**. What I wanted is that the files are placed inside subfolder based on their input in field `NAME`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- Your Google Form has 2 fields.

  1. Name
  2. Uploaded files button (In this case, multi files can be uploaded.)
- Both fields are set as the required fields.
- You want to move the uploaded files to the specific folder which has the folder name from the answer of 1st question "Name". In this case, you want to create the folder as the subfolder in a folder.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to use Google Apps Script.

### Usage:

#### 1. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Google Form. Please set the top folder ID of the subfolders you want to create. If you want to create the subfolders in the root folder, please set `root`.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "###";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

#### 2. Install OnSubmit trigger.

Please install OnSubmit event trigger as the installable trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

#### 3. Test script.

In order to test the sample script and trigger, please open the Google Form and put Name and upload the files and submit them. By this, the script is run by firing the installable OnSubmit trigger. And, the uploaded files are moved to the created folder which has the folder name of "Name".

In this sample script, when the same folder name is existing, the files are put to the existing folder.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: wow, awesome, thank you stranger! Btw, if i want to add prefix to each of filename with the field "Name", how to do that?

Comment: @noobsee Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand about your initial question was resolved. I'm glad for it. About your 2nd question, in this case, the filename of the uploaded file can be retrieved with `DriveApp.getFileById(id)`. I think that you can rename the uploaded file using this and `folderName`. The methods for this are `getName()` and `setName()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Comment: Yep taht work. Btw recently i got error when people with same name upload, which mean the folder with same name already exist. How do I added suffix with number "_1" '"_2" etc. Like "noobsee_1", "noobsee_2", for the folder name?

Comment: @noobsee Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question, in this case, it is required to modify my proposed script. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your 3rd question?

Comment: I just posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565806/how-to-automatically-rename-folder-based-on-uploaded-file-if-there-are-duplicate, thank you for the response :). Really appreciate it

Comment: You must use subFolder.next() if the folder is exist. If only subFolder is used, it will return Folder Iterator type (not Folder type) and then will produce an error to move the file.

Comment: @imilah Thank you for your comment. I didn't notice the error. I could update it from your comment.