# Google Form Upload files to specific drive with specific folder name based on 4th user input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google Forms where users can input text, upload documents etc.

I need the 4th item in the Form as the name of the subfolder within the Top Folder. I have logged the output I need, which can be seen underneath, but I cannot seem to name the created subfolder with the input.
Moreover, I get the following error message when I attempt his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted).

[image: Log - error]

As you can read from the error, it is not moving the files to the subfolder. The user can upload multiple files, and I want all files to be moved.

Here you can see the code I have. As you can tell, I am very new to the world of Google Apps Script, so I hope someone can help out a newbie :-)

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1lbd21iTZF2oT7vCGEZ";  // Top folder ID
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();
  console.log("Name: " + itemResponses[3].getResponse())

  // Preparing the filder
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Attempts to move all files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `console.log` each variable to see if you get the expected value? What does `console.log(ItemResponses[1])` or `console.log(ItemResponses[1].getResponse())` return? This will make your question more clear and people can answer without the need of assuming what could possibly go wrong. Assumptions are a waste of both your time and the answerer's time.

Comment: Perhaps your using the wrong 0nFormSubmit there's one for the form and one for spreadsheet.Check event object in the guides section of the documentation near the bottom

Comment: Thank you for the tips @Mario. I managed to find the correct input and I attempted to edit my post to make it more clear! Again, I really appreciate the help! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Cooper! I am using the corrent OnFormSubmit - from forms :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### `itemResponses[1].getResponse()` is probably not an Array

From the documentation page of [getResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse)

> #### Return
>
> Object — a `String` or `String[]` or `String[][]` of answers to the question item

So it looks like you may be getting a simple `String` response, and since it is not an array, it has no `forEach` method.

As Marios suggested, try something like this to debug further:

```js
// Attempts to move all files to the folder.
// DEBUG
// itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
Logger.log(itemResponses)
Logger.log(itemResponses[1])
// This will be something that it not an array, probably a string.
Logger.log(itemResponses[1].getResponse())
```