# Google Form how to upload files and then place it into new folder based on the value submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

according to this question, [Google Form Upload files to specific new folder based on the value submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted/64531959#64531959?newreg=8bb6b745b60a4a37932dce2678bf6f90)

which lead to this code for google form script editor:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1HVTDe5YxYDolXrEaGebHOoypYqG38d_fkauOGg5hCAqQfw-amW5aIazflSJEl7THNGTn-nq3";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

i got an error saying: `TypeError: itemResponses[1].getResponse(...).forEach is not a function`

what should i do to get this code run succesfully?
i am completely new at this stuff, and any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

edit: Thank You @Tanaike !. It's cleared. Thank you for your help, this case is closed.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, I have a question. Can I ask you about the detail of your Google Form?

Comment: no, it's completely fine Tanaike, and thank you for your help and your code.  my google form consist of "Name" in drop-down type, "Date", and upload file option.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `my google form consist of "Name" in drop-down type, "Date", and upload file option.`, in your Google Form, 3 items, which are `"Name" in drop-down type`, `"Date"` and `upload file option`, are existing. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes Tanaike, it is correct. Thank you for your code before and your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that your `upload file option` is put to the 3rd item. So, when you modified `itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));` to `itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));`, what result will you obtain? Because, the 1st index of the array is `0`. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide the sample Google Form for replicating the issue?

Comment: i got `Error
Exception: The parameters (DriveApp.FolderIterator) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo.` on that line that you gave @Tanaike.
Sure, i'll give you my form sample, here it is https://forms.gle/Np9MRfTwpATR85Hr5.

Comment: hey @Tanaike i am really thankful for your help. it is finally cleared and done and worked like a charm! This case is closed. Sorry if i am too newbie in this case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: alright i already posted it as an aswer @Tanaike. again, thank you very much!

Comment: I also receive the error ' The parameters (DriveApp.FolderIterator) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify

```
itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
```

to :

```
itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
```

that is the answer to my question, credit to @Tanaike.

here is the link of the comment to that answer:
[Google Form how to upload files and then place it into new folder based on the value submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814444/google-form-how-to-upload-files-and-then-place-it-into-new-folder-based-on-the-v?noredirect=1#comment119865388_67814444)