# Google Form Upload files to specific new folder based on the LIST value submitted

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms

According to my question, I found the souliton here, how i could manage uploaded files. [Google Form how to upload files and then place it into new folder based on the value submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814444/google-form-how-to-upload-files-and-then-place-it-into-new-folder-based-on-the-v)
(The answer "Solved")

Now, I would like to change the CHECKBOX to LIST. I want to reach that, the user could choose only one option here.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Now, I would like to change the CHECKBOX to LIST.`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly:

[image]