# when uploading google forms files to a custom folder only one file uploads

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I m using a code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted?newreg=bedf4cc177224b6fa39e042b8c37e42b)

My goal, which is half way accomplished, is as follows:

1. Create a sub folder based on respondent answer [done]
2. Add all files in the form to said sub folder [so far is adding only one file of multiples that I request under the form]
3. rename each file according to the type of file requested under question, and if multiple files under the same question are uploaded add, i.e.: "phototest" "phototest1"

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1gvlYEr-CJwFVNZVipNkVNV3ussNvgfhR";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
  }
```

Comment: Instead of `FormApp.getActiveForm(); ` use `e.source` and instead of `formResponses[formResponses.length-1]` use `e.response`. What question type correspons to `  itemResponses[2]`? How it was set? (Does it allow to upload multiple files?).

Comment: Hi Ruben,  yes the form allows for multiple responses. let me share the link here so you can better visualize the form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-SRYmb5OMVDWr1h1hTjUpPfUisVI0nAOsIPKM4PknI4Y9-w/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: @Rubén as for what question type corresponds to itemReponses[2] would be "store Name" thats how the folder created will be name on submit

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Please bear in mind that all the relevant details should be included directly in the question. In Google Apps Script / JavaScript the Array indexes are `0` based, meaning that the `itemResponses[2]` corresponds to the third question, the "store Name" is the second question. P.S. While links to external resources might be helpful you should not rely on people opening them to understand what is being asked / the issue.