# Select a folder based on one of the answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have prepared a form in which only two responses are downloaded (later there is also a field for uploading a file).

[image: selectedChoice]

I want the ulpoad folder to be set by selection (GB or BN). Folders already exist on Google Drive.

I am trying to modify a script [Google Form Upload files to specific new folder based on the value submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  if (itemResponses[1].getValue()= 0){
    const folderId = "1GlmowOXhttkdBHPYHuTUM3uLcZmND8xR7W7T_7GJmIdwkibEW4HlrDoSBKk_CLnofjJ8fxji";
    } else {
    const folderId = "1IayOn5hqvy1VO3gHas-rnO0rbssSG4T1"; 
  }  

  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
  itemResponses[3].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020280/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this [sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/upload-files) from Google’s documentation. You only need to change the folder ID where you have the folders “GB” and “BN”.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var mainFolder = "FOLDERID";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(mainFolder);
  var formName = itemResponses[1].getResponse(); // In case you change the order of items in the Google Form, make sure to change the itemResponses[#] based on the item you're reading
  var folder = getSubFolder_(destFolder, formName);

  // Gets the file upload response as an array to allow for multiple files.
  let fileUploads = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD")
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    // Moves the files to the destination folder.
    if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
      fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(folder);
      });
    }
}

function getSubFolder_(objParentFolder, subFolderName) {
  // Iterates subfolders of parent folder to check if folder already exists.
  const subFolders = objParentFolder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = subFolders.next();

    // Returns the existing folder if found.
    if (folder.getName() === subFolderName) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  // Creates a new folder if one doesn't already exist.
  return objParentFolder.createFolder(subFolderName)
}
```

**Notes:**

Make sure to add an OnSubmit trigger in the script editor.

[image]

Here’s the result of the script above. If you have questions, let me know.

[image]

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined onFormSubmit @ kod.gs:5

line 5:

  var itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

Comment: Works great, exactly as expected. 
A very helpful and professional answer!