# Linking file responses folder with form on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

### Kind of Introduction

Hello everyone, I'm currently working on a project in which I must run a script in order to create certain structure at Google Drive by making use of Google Apps Script.
In a nutshell, I execute a script from a custom menu created on a spreadsheet. This calls a function stored in a Google script file that creates a folder and a copy of a base form stored in another folder. Then it moves the copied form to the newly created folder. The responses of this form are stored in another spreadsheet created in the same folder. Then, the script creates a folder in where the file responses must be uploaded, but I'm not able to find a function which does that. (something that creates an already linked folder would also be very useful)

The structure I need to create is quite simple:

```
DriveApp
├── Form folder
│   ├── File upload folder
│   │   ├── (Here is where all uploaded files should be stored)
│   ├── Copied form
│   └── Form's replies spreadhseet
└── Base form
```

### Objective

I want to link that folder or, at least, create a new one in the desired destination. The process to replicate what I want to make made manually is to open the form without a file upload folder, and, then, clicking restore on this box popping up:

[image]

### Already Tried

At first, I tried searching in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form), but I wasn't able to find a function able to do what I wanted.

Then I started searching useful responses on StackOverflow. Almost everything I found was about uploading files to separated folders depending on the response of the user, but all of them had nothing to do with how I made the code. Finally, I tried to use the reply of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted), but it's of no use to me because I run into two problems.

- Firstly, I can't apply that to my code because it's an event generated every time a form is submitted. I must recall that my script is run through a spreadsheet, so I can't use it on a form where it is not defined.
- Secondly, if there was a way for me to make use of that event, I could not execute it due to the form having replies unabled. It seems that if a form that requires an upload doesn't have the folder to save the files, `form.isAcceptingResponses()` becomes false (which makes sense).

Maybe I should change my code and adapt it to make use of the `onFormSubmit` event? If so, how could I synchronize that with my original code?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: If I'm gathering this correctly, after creating a new folder containing the form/response sheet/ file upload folder, you would like all new file uploads in that form to be placed in that form's file upload folder?

Comment: Or do you mean that you are getting files from the Forms response and you want to upload those files in the `Forms Responses ` on that new folder?

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike No, there's no problem. I understand that your response was made for a determined situation. My problem is that I can't link the replies of a file upload question to a specific folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The structure I need to create is quite simple:`, what does "DriveApp" mean? And what is `folder` of `I want to link that folder or, at least, create a new one in the desired destination.`?

Comment: Sorry for replying this late. `DriveApp` stands for the whole google drive directory and `folder` is the directory where I want to store the uploaded files.