# Google Form Submit Files to Custom File Location is not Moving Uploaded File

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I am building a Google Form to upload files. I needed a custom solution so I created a script based of [this google setup tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/upload-files#setup.gs) and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted). The first answer in the form response is a **name** which I would like to use for the file name and the second answer contains the **uploaded files**. My issue lies in moving the uploaded files to the new folder.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  try{
    const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
    const responses = form.getResponses()[0];
    const answers = responses.getItemResponses()
    const NAME = answers[0].getResponse();
    const ID = responses.getId();
    const subfolder = folder.createFolder(NAME).setDescription(ID);
    console.log(answers[1].getResponse());
    answers[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(subfolder));
  }
  catch(error){console.log(error);}
}
```

This part is not working:

```
answers[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(subfolder));
```

Although the `id` works, the movement of the file(s) to the subfolder that was created is not doing anything. *What's the issue?* Any code cleanup is also welcome as this is my first time working with this type of code.

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result and your current issue, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, it supposes that your script is the container-bound script of Google Form. And, your function `onFormSubmit` has already been installed as the OnSubmit trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually) Please be careful about this.

In this modified script, when the Google Form is submitted, the uploaded file is put into the created subfolder by the script executed with the OnSubmit trigger.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID'); // Please set your folder ID.
  const [name, fileIds] = e.response.getItemResponses().map(f => f.getResponse());
  const subfolder = folder.createFolder(name).setDescription(e.response.getId());
  fileIds.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(subfolder));
}
```

- When you directly run this script, an error like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')` occurs because of no event object. Please be careful about this.
- When I tested this script, I confirmed that the uploaded file could be moved to the created subfolder.
- For example, if you want to directly run your script with the script editor, how about the following modification? In this modification, the latest response is used.

  ```js
  function onFormSubmit(e) {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID'); // Please set your folder ID.
    const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    const response = form.getResponses().pop();
    const [name, fileIds] = response.getItemResponses().map(f => f.getResponse());
    const subfolder = folder.createFolder(name).setDescription(response.getId());
    fileIds.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(subfolder));
  }
  ```

  In order to retrieve the latest response, I modified `const responses = form.getResponses()[0];` to `const response = form.getResponses().pop();`. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. But, this is just my guess.